# Translation of particle で in 「オーストラリアは今夏でとてもあついです」

Tags: translation, particle-で

> オーストラリアは　今　**夏で**　とても　あつい　です。

Does this sentence mean:

- “Australia is currently in **summer and** it's very hot”. Or,
- “Australia is now very hot **in summer**”.

---

I know that the Japanese sentence could follow the sentence pattern below.

> オーストラリアは　今　**夏です。**　とても　あつい　です。
>   オーストラリアは　今　**夏で、**　　とても　あつい　です。
>   (I have seen sentences where there is no comma after で.

[image: Mirai Book 5 2nd Edition, pg 6]

(All Rights reserved to Mirai Book 5 Company.)

---

Or, the **で** could be used to say, **"in summer"**.

Comment: 夏で never stands for "in summer" because 夏 is not a place but a season.

Answer (score 4):

> オーストラリアは　今　夏**で**　とても　あつい　です。
>   Does this sentence mean:
>   Australia is currently in Summer and it's very hot. 
>   Or,
>   Australia is now very hot in summer.

The former.

> =オーストラリアは今、夏です。+ とても暑いです。

The で is a 断定の助動詞「だ」, not a case particle(格助詞).

Answer (score 3):

Basicaly, you're asking if that で is the particle で or the suspensive/て form of だ. The thing is, those two often have very similar meaning.

If we think it's the particle で, it means that the summer is the direct cause of the heat :

> It's very hot in Australia right now because it's summer.

If we think it's the て form of だ, we just state two facts but with the idea that there is a causal link between them.

> It's summer in Australia right now and (that's why) it's very hot.

Long story short : It means the same thing.

Now, I don't know exactly what you meant when you wrote "Australia is now very hot in summer." : if the implied idea was that the summers have been hot in Australia for some years but that it hasn't always been the case, then I think the proper japanese sentence would be :

> オーストラリアは今**では**夏**の時**とてもあついです。
>
> Nowadays, Australia is very hot in summer/Australia's summers are very hot.

では indicates that there is a contrast between now and before, and I don't think で can replace の時 there but I  can't really explain why.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is current summer in Australia and it is very hot.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much. A rougher translation would be: "As for Australia, it is now very hot due to summer."  Would pretty much equates to "Australia is (now) very hot in summer."