# what is the use of で in 日本料理は京都の料理でたいへん美味しい

Tags: particle-で

found it at the kanji workbook of shin nihongo no kiso. 
would it be something like "among the japanese cuisine, kyoto's cuisine is specially tasty"?
I know that で is used to say "among" but the only example I know is using SでいちばんAdj

Comment: Is this sentence correct?  If I were to guess, it seems like it should be `京都の料理は日本料理でたいへん美味しい`.  Then it would have the meaning you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「[日本料理]{にほんりょうり}は[京都]{きょうと}の[料理]{りょうり}**で**たいへん[美味]{おい}しい。」

The content of the sentence is somewhat questionable, but it is a grammatical sentence and it can be analyzed as such.

***The 「で」 here is an auxiliary verb, not a particle***.  「で」 is the [連用形]{れんようけい} (the conjunctive / continuative form) of the affirmation auxiliary verb 「だ」. 　This 「で」 can be replaced by 「であり」.

The author could have used a **comma** and wrote:

「日本料理は京都の料理で、たいへん美味しい。」

It is saying **two separate things**, which is why you need a 連用形 to connect them.

1) Japanese cuisine is (or "means") Kyoto cuisine.

and

2) It is delicious.

Related:  [Translation of particle で in 「オーストラリアは今夏でとてもあついです」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21468/translation-of-particle-%e3%81%a7-in-%e3%82%aa%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%81%af%e4%bb%8a%e5%a4%8f%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a8%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e3%81%82%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99)